# Как просмотреть большой архив(10+ гб) tar.gz с помощью php?

Tags: php, tar, gzip

Есть архивы бекапов, их нужно просматривать "на лету", без разархивации. Пытался через `phar://` и `pharData`, в обоих попытках получаю 504 ошибку nginx. Как это вообще можно сделать? Я подозреваю что мне нужно читать просто без дочерних директорий архива, но как это сделать понять не могу.

Comment: Я б делал совсем не так. При поступлении нового файла сразу создавал бы его "образ" штатными программами, можно даже рендерить в готовый HTML. А при просмотре уже отдавать этот образ как статику или кусок шаблона. Идеальный вариант, если, конечно, архивы не падают с частотой сто штук в секунду :)

Comment: @PinkTux ты не мог бы подсказать по образу в чате?

Comment: Как получить список файлов см. [man tar](http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=tar&category=1). В самом простом случае это `tar -tvf имя_файла.tgz` Что с этим списком делать дальше - решать вам.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перелопачивать архив при каждом обращении с сайта - не самая лучшая идея. Да что там, просто плохая идея :) Правильней было бы создать список файлов в архиве заранее, и потом использовать его как шаблон для вывода.

Например, так:

```
#!/bin/sh

TEMPLATES="/var/templates/archives"
TEMPLATE=$(basename $1)

tar -tvf "$1" | awk '{print $6}' >> "$TEMPLATES/$TEMPLATE.txt"
```

Можно вызывать этот скрипт после создания/модификации архива на сервере. А можно в `crontab` прописать обход каталога с архивами и создание/обновление шаблонов, если требуется.

Comment: Мысль не плохая, но я предполагаю свободное перемещение по архиву как по папке, я додумал мысль с образом и пришел немного к другой структуре. Я бы с удовольствием это решение написал на shell, что бы выиграть по скорости, но знаю как такое реализовать только на php.

Comment: @alias, я показал только сам принцип. Никто не мешает вам отпарсить вывод `tar ...` сразу в шаблон с навигацией, блэкждеком и этимисамыми :)

Comment: мешает отсутствие знаний :) По этому на php

Comment: @alias, так и делайте на PHP или на чём угодно. Просто первичный "сырой" материал для этого куда проще и быстрей получить с помощью самого `tar`, чем разбирать архив средствами PHP.